# What are the main benefits of using augmented assignment operators?

Tags: python

Just curious if there are any benefits to using augmented assignment operators other than cleaner code?

Comment: Augmented assignments can behave differently and can be customized. See the duplicate. EDIT: In Python.

Comment: I removed the Java and Kotlin tags because this question has different answers in different languages.